# How can I make sure an image is displayed on the right page?

Tags: pdf, includegraphics

I'm new using Latex and I'm having an issue trying to display an image on the right page.
Here is the code that I'm running :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
    \section{Conclusion}
 
        \begin{figure}[ht!]
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.54,angle=90,origin=c]{Courbes/Bilan.png}
            \end{center}
            \caption{Bilan}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is what Latex compile :
[image: The result I currently get]

And here is the actual picture :
[image: The image]

The thing is that I would like the picture to take a little more place but if I'm increasing the scale variable to be 0.55, it goes on the next page

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Since it looks like there's no text following it, you can try to make LaTeX "think" it's smaller by adding `\vspace{-1cm)` just after the caption.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yeah I've been able to put it on the same page by putting ```\vspace{-20cm}``` but the caption of the image doesn't appear anymore (even with a larger ```\vspace``` like ```-500cm```)

Comment: There are limits applied to how large a float can be (before the next \clearpage).  You can use [ht!] to ignore those limits.

Comment: It is hard to help you if don't know which document class you use, how big are your images, what id document page lookout, etc. As mentioned @JohnKormylo, , you may need to change amount of page reserved for floats.

Comment: @Zarko I'm using a ```\documentclass[a4paper]{article}``` as document article and I've added the image alone in the pose if needed

Comment: There's a minimum portion of a page that must be occupied by text: `\textfraction`.  I think your "enlarged" figure just exceeds what's allowed, so try reducing the amount of text required: `\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.15}`.  (I don't understand why the suggestion to "shorten" the figure doesn't work, if the negative `\vspace` comes *after* the caption.)

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of your image which can be fit in page, which contain section title, can be

[image]

and obtained by:

```
\documentclass[a4paperm]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.95}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.05}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \section{Conclusion}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=\textwidth, width=0.9\textheight, keepaspectratio,
                 angle=90,origin=c]{Courbes/Bilan.png}
            \caption{Bilan}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

\textwidth

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the figure environment:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \section{Conclusion}
    \begin{center}
       \includegraphics[scale=0.54,angle=90,origin=c]{Courbes/Bilan.png}
       \captionof{figure}{Bilan}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The purpose of `figure` is to allow the image to float to where TeX thinks best.  If you don't want that, then you can change the size however you want.